# Is it possible to use langchain to chat with in-house elasticsearch engine

Tags: elasticsearch, langchain

I'm new to Langchain. I see some examples of lanchain with elasticsearch, but they are all get result from somewhere and create index into elasticsearch. We already have an in-house elasticsearch engines with some indexes **for years**, I wonder if it's possible to use langchain to make chat with this search engine and get ai responses? How can I do it? Can anyone kindly show me a piece of codes?

Comment: Here are two interesting blog articles on the subject: https://www.elastic.co/blog/privacy-first-ai-search-langchain-elasticsearch and https://www.elastic.co/blog/large-language-models-elastic-code-langchain

Comment: I've read them. They both just get data and do embedding and create index into elasticsearch vector store for later queries for ai response. As I've said in my question, We have a proprietary elasticsearch engine for years, I wish to chat with it and get ai responses using llmchain. They are different issues.

Comment: I've found an article from Elastic. Its purpose is just what I want to do, only I wish to use langchain: https://www.elastic.co/blog/chatgpt-elasticsearch-openai-meets-private-data

Comment: @ScottChu did you find a solution?